# How to solve this logarithmic equation whose expressions have different bases?

Tags: logarithms

I have been trying to solve the following equation for a while and i can't seem to figure it out, your help would be greatly appreciated. Here is the equation: $3^x$=$5^{x-1}$

Comment: If $x$ is an integer, there is no solution. If $a$and $b$ are coprime, then $a^m=b^n$ has no solutions for integer $n$ and $m$

Comment: Take the logarithm of both sides, any base you like. I would use the natural logarithm (base $e$), but if you prefer $10$, that's fine too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

$$5^{x-1}=\frac {5^x}5\\
\frac{a^q}{b^q}=\left(\frac ab\right)^q$$

Comment: I had considered this but did not think it was the right thing to do. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** $$\log_3(5^{x-1})=(x-1)\log_3(5)$$

Comment: Or, perhaps more practically, $\ln(5^{x-1})=(x-1)\ln 5$. +1 for you either way.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the steps 
$$ 3^x=5^{x-1} $$
$$ 1=\frac{5^{x-1}}{3^x}= 5^{x-1}3^{-x} $$
$$ 1= e^{\ln(5^{x-1}3^{-x})} = e^{\ln(5^{x-1})+\ln(3^{-x})} $$
$$ \ln(1)= \ln(5^{x-1})+\ln(3^{-x}) $$
$$ 0= (x-1)\ln(5)-x\ln(3) $$
$$ \ln(5)= x\ln(5)-x\ln(3) $$
$$ \ln(5)= x(\ln(5)-\ln(3)) $$
$$ x=\frac{\ln(5)}{\ln(5)-\ln(3)} $$

Answer (score 0):

$$
(\frac53)^x = 5
$$
$$
x = \frac{\ln 5}{\ln \frac53} =...
$$